# Tensorflow: estimator saving eval metrics to /eval_0 not /eval

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I decided to give early stopping a shot with [stop_if_no_decrease_hook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/stop_if_no_decrease_hook) but after tweaking the params and making sure the hook was actually being triggered, discovered an oddity with my estimator.

The hook reads eval data from the directory [specified by estimator.eval_dir()](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/early_stopping.py#L391) which in this case pops out "trained_models/rcnn_inception_v2/eval". This looks all good until I check my actual directory structure and find that /eval doesn't exist. Instead, I have eval_0/ (containing the proper logs) with no other directories in the rcnn_inception_v2/ folder.

I'm curious why eval_0/ is being created instead of eval/ when I've done nothing special to specify this directory. And importantly on top of that, why does estimator.eval_dir() return the wrong directory?